# Mudar cursor no evento "onhover" para HTML5 <video>

Tags: html, css, html5-video

Quero mudar o cursor para uma "mão" quando passo o rato por cima dos botões:

- Play
- Stop
- Volume
- Fullscreen etc..

para um player de vídeo *HTML5*. De momento, o ponteiro do rato quando passa por cima do reprodutor não dá ideia que se pode interagir com o mesmo. Como posso corrigir isso, visto que não faço ideia como mudar o *CSS* desses mesmo botões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dei uma pesquisada e vi que existem esses pseudo-elementos que talvez você possa usar:

```
 video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button

 video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container

 video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider

 video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
```

Aqui ta a lista completa com mais detalhes: [webkit-pseudo-elements](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334)

Me baseei na seguinte questão:[CSS cursor style for html5 video elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126921/why-do-no-user-agents-implement-the-css-cursor-style-for-video-elements)

Comment: por acaso tinha tentado com isso, antes de fazer a pergunta, mas devo ter usado o elemento errado. Funciona 5*

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a classe abaixo ou a propriedade css `cursor: pointer;` na div que deseja:

```
.cursor_pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Exemplo:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=pointer

Referência:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Outras possibilidades para utilizar como cursor:

- auto
- cell
- copy
- crosshair
- default
- grab
- grabbing
- help
- move
- none
- not-allowed
- progress
- text
- wait
- zoom-in
- zoom-out
- initial